# Kendo UI or Sencha Touch for both web and mobile

Tags: kendo-ui, sencha-touch, kendo-mobile

I am evaluating the UI framework for my next project. We've to give support to browsers on desktop, mobile and tablet. I've gone through the features and examples of kendo ui and sencha touch.

We will be using following ui controls in the application.

- button, textbox, tab, bar chart, image, dropdown, textarea, grid, listview,
  calendar

Both frameworks support these elements and all the elements can be made available via responsive design. My question is shall I use Kendo UI or Sencha Touch for both (desktop and touch devices) or shall I go for separate code base ???

If I am using same code base for all three platforms, what am I losing and what will be the advantages ???? Please throw some light on deciding Kendo UI or Sencha Touch.

Please explain in detail if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your selection of the frameworks are good for your project. The UI controls which you have mentioned are well supported in both the frameworks(Though calendar is not directly supported but plugins are available to use).

Inspite of having so many similarities in between these two frameworks like:

1. Both are HTML5 based
2. Can be used to build mobile website, hybrid app and web app
3. Gives native look and feel of mobile applications

, there are some sharp features which sencha-touch provides:

1. If you are going for a complex app with lots of visual interaction. I strongly recommend using Sencha Touch.
2. Sencha Touch is also available in free license(kendo-ui is not)
3. Good number of third party plugin is available like [this](https://github.com/SwarmOnline/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar) for Calendar
4. Excellent in-house native app wrapping/packaging system via phonegap

And using sencha-touch you can easily make app for all three platforms you want. And at the end you are losing nothing but gains lots of forum and technical team support as Sencha is the most popular among HTML5 frameworks.